# ggplots not displaying in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Right now I am trying to build a shinyApp from an alcohol consumption dataset from the world health organization. I've built maps from this data and gotten those outputs to work, but right now I am trying to display the top ten countries in terms of drinks consumed and two of the plots are not displaying (For beer and wine).

You can see what I mean by looking at my shiny app here:

https://mdsil11.shinyapps.io/worldMap/

The weird thing is, my code works when I use simpler plots in place of the ggplotones like hist(rnorm(100)). Another weird thing is that these plots work when I run them in a regular R script. Finally, my last plot(the plot for spirits, or mixed drinks) displays but not for wine or beer.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
[library(rworldmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)


## defining datasets
wineDrinks = drinks\[ , c(2,5)\]
spiritDrinks = drinks\[ , c(2,4)\]
beerDrinks = drinks\[ , c(2,3)\]

topWine <- wineDrinks %>% arrange(desc(wine_servings))
topBeer <- beerDrinks %>% arrange(desc(beer_servings))
topSpirits <- spiritDrinks %>% arrange(desc(spirit_servings))

top10beer <- topBeer[0:10, ]
top10wine <- topWine[0:10, ]
top10spirits <- topSpirits[0:10, ]

## defining map objects
w <- joinCountryData2Map(drinksISO, joinCode = 'ISO3', nameJoinColumn = 'ISO', verbose = TRUE)
s <- joinCountryData2Map(drinksISO, joinCode = 'ISO3', nameJoinColumn = 'ISO', verbose = TRUE)
b <- joinCountryData2Map(drinksISO, joinCode = 'ISO3', nameJoinColumn = 'ISO', verbose = TRUE)

##### Shiny Application #####

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel('Global Alcohol Consumption'),
  #each input should have a unique input ID
  sidebarPanel(
  radioButtons(inputId = 'Alc', label = 'Alcohol Type',
              choices = list('Beer','Wine','Spirits'))
  )
  , mainPanel(
    plotOutput('map'), plotOutput('TopTen')
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderPlot({
    if(input$Alc == 'Beer'){
      mapCountryData(mapToPlot = b,nameColumnToPlot = 'beer_servings', mapTitle = 'World Beer Consumption',  missingCountryCol = "grey", oceanCol = "lightblue1")
    }

    if(input$Alc == 'Wine'){
      mapCountryData(mapToPlot = w,nameColumnToPlot = 'wine_servings', mapTitle = 'World Wine Consumption',  missingCountryCol = "grey", oceanCol = "lightblue1")
    }

    if(input$Alc == 'Spirits'){
      mapCountryData(mapToPlot = s, nameColumnToPlot = 'spirit_servings', mapTitle = 'World Spirits Consumption',  missingCountryCol = "grey", oceanCol = "lightblue1")
    }

  })


  output$TopTen <- renderPlot({

     #### PROBLEM LIES HERE #####

    if(input$Alc == 'Beer'){
      ggplot(top10beer,aes(x = reorder(country, -beer_servings), y = beer_servings)) + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_segment(aes(x = country, xend = country, y = 0, yend = beer_servings)) + labs(title="Lollipop Chart", subtitle = 'Top 10 beer drinking countries') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6)) + xlab('Countries')
    }
    if(input$Alc == 'Wine'){
      ggplot(top10wine, aes(x = reorder(country, -wine_servings), y = wine_servings)) + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_segment(aes(x = country, xend = country, y = 0, yend = wine_servings)) + labs(title="Lollipop Chart", subtitle = 'Top 10 wine drinking countries') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6)) + xlab('Countries')
    }

   #### BUT THIS WORKS ####

    if(input$Alc == 'Spirits'){
      ggplot(top10spirits,aes(x = reorder(country, -spirit_servings), y = spirit_servings)) + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_segment(aes(x = country, xend = country, y = 0, yend = spirit_servings)) + labs(title="Lollipop Chart", subtitle = 'Top 10 spirit drinking countries') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6)) + xlab('Countries')
    }
  }
  )

}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help/pointers on getting the other two plots to show would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Change those separate `if` statements to an `if/else/else`. Your `renderPlot` code block needs to return a ggplot object. If the last line of your block is an `if`, and that evaluates to FALSE, nothing is returned from the block. The values from previous `if` statements are basically ignored. Calling `ggplot()`doesn't actually draw the plot in the same way base graphics functions like `hist` do. You actually need to print the value returned by `ggplot` in order to trigger the plot to draw.

Here's one way to re-write your block.

```
output$TopTen <- renderPlot({

    if(input$Alc == 'Beer'){
      ggplot(top10beer,aes(x = reorder(country, -beer_servings), y = beer_servings)) + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_segment(aes(x = country, xend = country, y = 0, yend = beer_servings)) + labs(title="Lollipop Chart", subtitle = 'Top 10 beer drinking countries') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6)) + xlab('Countries')
    } else if(input$Alc == 'Wine'){
      ggplot(top10wine, aes(x = reorder(country, -wine_servings), y = wine_servings)) + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_segment(aes(x = country, xend = country, y = 0, yend = wine_servings)) + labs(title="Lollipop Chart", subtitle = 'Top 10 wine drinking countries') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6)) + xlab('Countries')
    } else if (input$Alc == 'Spirits'){
      ggplot(top10spirits,aes(x = reorder(country, -spirit_servings), y = spirit_servings)) + geom_point(size = 3) + geom_segment(aes(x = country, xend = country, y = 0, yend = spirit_servings)) + labs(title="Lollipop Chart", subtitle = 'Top 10 spirit drinking countries') + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=65, vjust=0.6)) + xlab('Countries')
    } else {
        stop("unknown plot type")
    }
})
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. I tried what you suggested and everything works perfectly. Thank you!!!